# What official English words describe these activities?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, finance

Court man goes to bank, and ask for information about suspect's account.

Court man goes to bank, and ask for taking steps to control suspect's account, 
such as freeze suspect's account or unfreeze it.

-------------- some background -----------

I am a software developer, and working on a software system that connect courts and banks in our country, so courts  can use this system to get account information such as how much balance left and then may freeze suspect's account.
all these have legal basis.

Comment: The action seems to be related with **execution of a warrant** but I don't understand your question as it is not clear without any context.

Comment: I think the question is better suited to ELL because it's clear the OP has difficulty with  describing the situation. Who is this "court man" someone delegated by the judge/magistrate?

Comment: @Mari-LouA sorry, I did't notice that there is a another site for English learning. Do you know how to move my question to there ?

Comment: I think your edit has cleared up a number of issues I had, you've also received two good answers. Wait a while before accepting, other users may also contribute.

Answer (score 3):

The bank would only allow this if it is obeying an order specific to the account; if so, either such order could be described as an *injunction*, and the first might be a *subpoena*.

Answer (score 2):

Depening on the jurisdiction you are in and the details of the proceedings, the *[sherriff](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sherrif)*, *[bailiff](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bailiff)* or *[process server](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/process-server)* might *[seize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/siezing)*, *[impound](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impounding)*, *[poind](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poinding)* or *[sequestrate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sequestrate)* the bank account.

Edit: corrected spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to a ***Bank Account Levy:***

> - When a bank account is frozen due to a creditor trying to get the debtor to repay its debt. A bank levy can occur due to either unpaid taxes or unpaid debt. The IRS usually uses this method the most, but other creditors can use this method as well.

(Investopedia)

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, those actions need proper "**execution of a [warrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_(law))**" which is usually issued by a judge

> (1) to permits an otherwise illegal act that would violate individual
>   rights and
>
> (2) affords the person executing the writ protection from damages if
>   the act is performed.

If the purpose of the system is to check the balance of any account, it is called a [**search warrant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_warrant) and if it is to freeze an account, it is **seizure (or attachment) warrant**.

Note: The name of the warrants could be different depending on jurisdiction.

Even if you establish a system between the court and banks for those specific actions, you would have to establish **authorization system** where related parties are required to input warrant numbers or other verification codes and verify them.

[Wikipedia]